# What's the name of this connector, used to connect a mains power cable to the PCB of a RadioShack 42-3067 xenon strobe?

Tags: identification, connector, mains, power-connector

The power cord for a RadioShack 42-3067 xenon strobe got damaged very close to the appliance, so I need to replace it. I assume the connector on the end used to attach it to the PCB isn't reusable, so I'll need to get a new one.

Here's the part in question:

[image]
[image]

And here's what it attaches to on the board:

[image]
[image]

What's the name or part number of it?

Comment: TE/AMP MTA series perhaps. Header looks like many others e.g. Molex KK, SPOX, depending on pitch, pin size, exact curve of the holding tab, etc.

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://au.element14.com/multicomp-pro/mp008484/conn-r-a-header-2pos-1row-3-96mm/dp/3817334?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-alte

Answer (score 4):

I assume the pitch is 3.96 mm.

My [Identconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=single_wall_conn_4&fl=0000000000000000000000000000200000-404-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) Identifies it as a plug for a Single-wall wire-to-board connectors, 3.96 mm, no latch, Insulation displacement.

Made by multiple manufacturers:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Adam tech](https://app.adam-tech.com/products/index/keywords:LHB#search) - LHB LHC LHD + MTD - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7cd8hz50)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/intersection/mta-100-mta-156-connectors.html) - MTA-156 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/mqtbq302)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/intersection/mta-100-mta-156-connectors.html) - MTA-156 4w - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/21cf2b3t)

https://www.digikey.com/short/h95c2nmd

[image: TE MTA]

{DigiKey}

If the pitch is 2.54 mm, then it's [this](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=single_wall_conn_2p5&fl=0000000000000000000000000000200000-404-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C).

Comment: Compared to the 0.3” 1/4W R body, the pitch looks like 0.2” than 3.96 mm . Someone should measure this . Hint

Answer (score 2):

These are called “wire to board” plugs for single row heavy duty headers.

The connector is defined by : Pitch , square pin width, length and interlock may be vendor unique.

To me it looks closer to 0.2” or the std 5.08 mm.

Look for shell and socket terminals separately.

5.08mm LK & LKX & LKS BOARD TO WIRE